# Showing a Google map with a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I've tried to put together a single script which shows a google map when the button click and then reads the coordinates from two input fields.

This is the code I have written: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/2r9tC/3/

```
// MAP DISPLAY CODE
function mapDisplay() {

var latval = $('input[id=lat]').val();
var lngval = $('input[id=lng]').val();    

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latval, lngval),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions)
});

// 
$(function() {
    $('#action').click(mapDisplay);
});
```

I'm really not having any luck so I was wondering if someone could tell me where I have gone wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo

```
function mapDisplay() {
    // ...
}); <--
```

The extra `)` was the problem

[**Fixed it here**.](http://jsfiddle.net/2r9tC/8/)

Answer (score 2):

if `map_canvas` div is hidden on document load then modify your code as below:

```
function mapDisplay() {

var latval = $('input[id=lat]').val();
var lngval = $('input[id=lng]').val();    

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latval, lngval),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
}


    $('#action').click(function(){
        $( "#map_canvas" ).show();
    });
```

Or if you want to call the function as well:

```
    $('#action').click(function(){
        mapDisplay();
        $( "#map_canvas" ).show();
    });
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it...

Comment: The thing I noticed was the }); at the end of the function... it was redundant

Comment: Tried to implement this here but it isn't even getting hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/2r9tC/13/

Comment: Try this now [ http://jsfiddle.net/2r9tC/15/ ]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is that you need an API Key for google maps.  Your fiddle code does not include the key (nor should it given it is publicly viewable)

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/google_maps_api_key.asp) explains this in detail.

Comment: You don't need an API key for google maps since V3